# unable to use Spring Advice(@Before) using annotations

Tags: spring, aop, spring-annotations

I am new to springs and trying to run a simple java application with java advices....

xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"> 
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="com.cts.two.Advices"/>
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>    
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.two"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Advice Class

```
package com.cts.two;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
@Aspect
public class Advices implements Adv{    

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.cts.two.*.*(..))")
    public void advice(){

    }
    @Before("advice()")
    public void before(JoinPoint name) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("inside advices");
        /*System.out.println(name.getClass() + " this is get class");
        System.out.println(name.getSignature().getName() + " this is the get signatue and get name");*/
    }
}
```

class on which advice needs to be applied...I want the before method of Advice class to be executed before below mentioned test() method

```
package com.cts.two;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component

public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b= new ClassB();

    public void setB(ClassB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("inside classA test");
        //b.test();
    }

}
```

caller of methods/test class/main class

```
package com.cts.two;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CallerAB {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "AllAnnotations.xml");
        ClassA calledA = (ClassA) context.getBean("classA");
        calledA.test();
    }

}
```

the problem is that when I run the code directly the test method of class A is executed but the advice is not...
Kindly advice..
Am i missing something ???
AspectJ 1.6.12 jar is also added...

Answer (score 2):

Aspects should be decalred as beans.

`@Aspect` doesn't do it automatically, `<aop:include>` doesn't do it as well (it sets additional restriction on beans that can be used as aspects).

So, you need

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Advices implements Adv { ... }
```

and don't need `<aop:include>`.

Comment: Annotate aspect class with `@Component` to make it visible to `<context:component-scan>`, or just declare it XML as `<bean>`.

Comment: yup did that but.....still the advice isn't called...directly the test method of class is called.......

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer from @axtavt you need to add the `@Component` annotation. But you also need to remove the `<aop:include>`. Your spring wiring xml should just be:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.two"/>
```

As stated in the [spring AOP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-aj-configure), the `name` attribute in the `<aop:include>` element is supposed to be a bean name, not a class name. Specifying a bean explicitly overrides Spring's auto-detection and specifying it incorrectly means that there is no aspect used at all.